# Limitations per reCaptcha (Google) account

Tags: recaptcha

Is there a limit of domain names a single Google/reCaptcha account is allowed?

In our use case we would create one site with single domain in site per account that we provision. So how many sites can we have under a single account?

I know (have tested this) that there is limit of 50 domains per site. But I can not find anything on the limit of sites.

We would need certainly more than 10k sites (each with single domain) - and no we can not bundle multiple domains per site as each domain must have unique security key.